# Local environment, User Level Root setup

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, server-name

I'm setting up this OSX Mavericks following this [guide](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-9-mavericks/) but I cannot get `http://localhost/~giulio` to work ('giulio' is this mac username).

Looks like it doesn't find the `/users/giulio.conf`

This is what's inside the `/private/var/log/apache2/error_log`

> [Thu Feb 27 13:54:41 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>
> [Thu Feb 27 13:54:48 2014] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
>
> httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using iMac-di-Giulio.local for ServerName
>
> [Thu Feb 27 13:54:48 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
>
> [Thu Feb 27 13:54:48 2014] [notice] Digest: done
>
> [Thu Feb 27 13:54:48 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.17 mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/0.9.8y configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Thu Feb 27 13:54:55 2014] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/index-maintenance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved redoing the whole process and adding `Servername Localhost`
and adding the follwing code into `giulio.conf` file into `users` folder.

```
<Directory "/Users/giulio/Sites/">
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```